# How to create an automatic nested list and sub-lists with letters and/or Roman numerals in R-markdown?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I am trying to generate a nested list with numbers, letters, and Roman numerals. R-Markdown cheatsheet shows

1. ordered list
2. item 2

   - sub-item 1
   - sub-item 2

but, this generates a sub-list with an unordered bullet. Instead of this, I need sub-list with letters and sub-sub-lists with Roman numerals like this:

```
1. What geoms would you use to draw the followings?
   a. A line chart
      i) `geom_line()`
   b. A boxplot
      ii) `geom_boxplot()`
```

Is there any way to do this? Thank you,

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What kind of input do you want to use, if it is "without typing"?

Comment: I was trying to mean without specifying its order. For example, you just need to type \item and LaTeX will generate the bullets in order in enumerate. You don't need to type a, b, c or i, ii, iii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, I have found the answer to my question in another [R-Markdown cheatsheet](https://ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/math/statistics/sfs/Education/Advanced%20Studies%20in%20Applied%20Statistics/course-material-1719/Datenanalyse/rmarkdown-2.pdf). The point is to put **4 spaces** or **2 indents** before the sub-list items and **8 spaces** or **4 indents** before the sub-sub-list items. The following is my code in R-Markdown:

```
1. What geoms would you use to draw the followings?
    a. A line chart
        i. `geom_bar()`
        i. `geom_line()`
    a. A boxplot  
        i. `geom_boxplot()`
        i. box
    a. A histogram: `geom_histogram()`
    a. An area chart: `geom_area()`
```

The output is like this:

```
1. What geoms would you use to draw the followings?
    a. A line chart
        i. `geom_bar()`
        ii. `geom_line()`
    b. A boxplot  
        iii. `geom_boxplot()`
        iv. box
    c. A histogram: `geom_histogram()`
    d. An area chart: `geom_area()`
```